# How to check string pattern in laravel validation?

Tags: laravel

Is there any way to validate string pattern in laravel ?
I want to check that string pattern is something like this:
1-2-3

Answer (score 2):

You can validate your requests by doing:

```php
$request->validate([
    'somefield' => 'regex:/\d-\d-\d/'
]);
```

[Docs](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/validation#rule-regex)